Full Network Enumeration without an assigned ip address
I've faced a situation where I connected to a network with an ethernet cable and the DHCP server was disabled, so I didn't get an assigned ip. I was wondering if I can run a scan with kali linux tools on the network to identify the gateway, the network range and the available ip addresses that I can assign to my device.

Without a DHCP server, your computer will likely have a
private IP-address, which the router will not understand and so
will not transmit any request that
involves IP addresses not in the private network range.
However, in general, IP addresses are used on the
Internet layer :

The internet layer is a group of internetworking methods, protocols, and specifications in the Internet protocol suite that are used to transport network packets from the originating host across network boundaries; if necessary, to the destination host specified by an IP address.

However, this protocol operates above a lower level which is the
Link layer :

In computer networking, the link layer is the lowest layer in the Internet protocol suite, the networking architecture of the Internet. The link layer is the group of methods and communications protocols confined to the link that a host is physically connected to. The link is the physical and logical network component used to interconnect hosts or nodes in the network and a link protocol is a suite of methods and standards that operate only between adjacent network nodes of a network segment.

And also :

The core protocols specified by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) in this layer are the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP), the Reverse Address Resolution Protocol (RARP), and the Neighbor Discovery Protocol (NDP), which is a facility delivering similar functionality as ARP for IPv6.

As there exist in this layer protocols that issue requests without
using IP addresses, it is possible to sort of use them to scan the
network. The amount of information that can be gathered would be
limited and would mostly include MAC addresses and IP addresses.
